# Is indexing of color independent from pixel sampling, or do they interact, and how?

Tags: downsampling, color

My partner stitches, and uses sites like https://www.pixel-stitch.net/ in order to produce patterns.

These sites do two things: they downsample an image in space to produce fewer pixels, but they also sample the colors in an image to have fewer colors of thread to use.

My intuition is that the naive way to do both of these things (average the color of adjacent pixels, and then map the downsampled image to a minimal set of colors) probably doesn't produce the best results. Or at the very least, algorithms result from optimizing for different qualities (e.g. perceptual accuracy, fewest colors, trading off some of one for some of the other).

Is there research in this area? Is my intuition right that the naive way is not best? Any thoughts as to how to approach this problem?

Comment: It's rather likely that any change of the method will lead to practically indistinguishable results, because the medium of delivery is of such low fidelity.

Comment: We cannot know how an individual website processes the image. However, resampling image down to a smaller resolution, and generating an optimum palette for a given amount of colors have been a part of daily use of image processing (drawing/editing) programs for over 3 decades.